# cis.upenn.edu cis194 Haskell Basics: Functions and Pictures

Tags: haskell

#### Animations

Now the traffic light is green, but we want it to switch to red every now and then. The CodeWorld API not only allows us to draw drawings, but also to run animations. What is an animation? It is a picture that changes over time, where time can conveniently be understood as the number of seconds since the start of the animation.

In imperative language, one would probably have a `getCurrentTime()` function and call that from somewhere in our drawing generating. This is not possible nor desirable in a pure functional language, as it would be a hidden side effect. Instead, the time is provided as a parameter.

So here this codes makes the traffic light switch every three seconds:

```
trafficController :: Double -> Picture
trafficController t
  | round (t/3) `mod` 2 == 0 = trafficLight True
  | otherwise                = trafficLight False

main :: IO ()
main = animationOf trafficController
```

#### Questions:

1. How can the function `trafficController` work without the `t` input in the `main` statement if it is defined (above) to work with time parameter?
2. What makes the `t` parameter increment all the time ?

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: The questions came about while trying to do Homework 1 of the cis194 course, but they are actually general questions' regarding Haskell and CodeWorld - API

Answer (score 1):

1. `animationOf`'s type is [`(Double -> Picture) -> IO ()`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codeworld-api-0.2.0.0/docs/CodeWorld.html). This means its argument has to have type `Double -> Picture`, i.e. it must be a function from `Double` to `Picture`. `trafficController` is a function with precisely this type. Note that `trafficController t` (for some `Double` `t`) isn't: it's a `Picture`!
2. The definition of `animationOf`, which you can find [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/codeworld-api-0.2.0.0/docs/src/CodeWorld-Driver.html). If you look into what it does with its argument, and then the functions it calls, etc., it ultimately calls its parameter (`trafficController` in this case) with different `t` repeatedly. However, it requires tracing a few steps, and I wouldn't recommend it at this stage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,however, you missed answering my two questions or I did not understand them. My Questions referred to the "trafficController" and its usage as input to the animation function. The "trafficController" function which by its definition should receive an input parameter (t) while in its actual usage receive none, and still all the code works perfectly

Comment: It does receive an input parameter. It is passed to `animationOf` as a function. You can see more clearly what is going on by doing eta expansion: `animationOf trafficController` means the same as `animationOf (\x -> trafficController x)`, by eta expansion.

Comment: @Atir I've extended the answers. Hopefully it's more clear now. Note that 1. is the answer to your first question, and 2. to the second one.